# Replication on a clustered Instance

Tags: sql-server, clustering, transactional-replication, high-availability

Can I set up Replication on a clustered Instance of 2 Nodes. If yes then is it mandatory to have a 3 separate Instances for Distributor, Publisher and lastly Subscriber . If there is a fail over then will the replication break ?

Comment: I've set up replication on a clustered 2 node instance before where one server was the Distributor / Publisher / Subscriber. When the instance fails over, both nodes run on one server so replication should not be impacted minus the small time when the node has to fail over.

Comment: I've done this and yes, it acts just like a regular replication process clustered or unclustered.  If you somehow are dealing with shares for snapshots and so fourth ensure it is done properly if it is not on shared disks, or just put it on shared disks as part of the cluster resource.

Comment: Just to clarify the snapshot folder will be created on the clustered resource(disk) and the service account for the distributor/subscriber/publisher will need to have read write permission on that folder.

Comment: Can I create the snapshot folder on the instance which is the distributor/publisher and the subscriber as well ?

Answer (score 1):

Replication doesn't care about or interact with clustering.

Replication is set up from SQL instance to SQL instance, the physical host that the instance happens to be running on at that moment isn't relevant.

If a failover occurs, a momentary interruption in replication will be experienced as the instance goes offline, but will resume once SQL comes up on the other host.

> If yes then is it mandatory to have a 3 separate Instances for Distributor, Publisher and lastly Subscriber?

What? No.

You can have a *single* SQL instance be the distributor, publisher, AND subscriber if you want to. (Not common, but possible to push changes from one database to another on the same host.)

A more typical configuration is to have two SQL instances (a publisher/distributor and a subscriber).

But all of those business decisions are completely independent of clustering.

Comment: Thanks so the set up will be just like a normal replication set up

Comment: @SqlNovice Should be, yes.